# cannot configure CUPS on elementary OS juno

Tags: release-juno

Everytime I try to add a printer, I get this error: Unauthorized
Enter your username and password or the root username and password to access this page. If you are using Kerberos authentication, make sure you have a valid Kerberos ticket.

How where do I enter my user name/password.

Help please.  Thanks.

Comment: Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the cups! do not open the interface. By doing so you will solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to open [CUPS](http://localhost:631/admin/) in Chrome will NOT work (no authentication window is displayed)! This is a Chrome "feature", where they decided to prevent popups from and dialogs when accessing non-https locations. It works though in Firefox and Epiphany. I recommend Firefox, because Epiphany seems to have some issues displaying the button labels :D