# How to Install Network Printer using PPD File on JUNO

Tags: release-juno, printer

We don't use USB printers at work, and so I need to add Network Printer using PPD File on JUNO.

Thanks,

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using CUPS to install the printer:

1. Visit http://localhost:631/admin/ in Firefox (it will NOT work in Chrome -> see [cannot configure CUPS on elementary OS juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20924/9445)
   )
2. Click on Add Printer
3. Login with your elementary OS user and password
4. Choose your printer's connection protocol
5. Click Continue
6. Type your printer's path in the Connection filed
7. Click on Continue
8. Type a name and description
9. Click on Continue
10. Click on Browse, select your PPD file and click on Add Printer

You could also install CUPS GUI, from Terminal:

```
sudo apt install system-config-printer

system-config-printer
```

Hope this helps.